# Correct way to access JavaScript object property

Tags: javascript

I do not see the error to access a property of this object:

```
console.log(routes);
[Object { bounds=((-34.76335, -58.21068), (-34.749880000000005, -58.202540000000006)),  copyrights="Datos de mapas ©2016 Google",  legs=[1],  más...}]
console.log(routes.legs);
```

undefined

or `console.log(routes["legs"]);`

is similar: undefined

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: actually, i do not see, how your object/array??? look like. maybe you do something like this with your object and add the text, you get: `document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4) + '</pre>');`

Comment: `routes` appears to be an array containing a single object ? Try `routes[0]["legs"]`

Comment: `routes` is an array _containing_ an object. Do `routes[0].legs`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: What is expected result of `((-34.76335, -58.21068), (-34.749880000000005, -58.202540000000006))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your console printed out, routes is an array containing an Object, so you could try adding an index before selecting a key in the object.
So, for example:

```
console.log(routes[0]["legs"]);
// or
console.log(routes[0].legs);
```